# nested substitutions in python

Tags: python, string, replace, nested

I need to filter a (long) text file replacing patterns, possibly nested.

Unfortunately patterns are somewhat ambiguous (what follows is not the full list):

- `\textit{whatever}` -> `@e{whatever}e@`
- `\textbf{whatever}` -> `@b{whatever}b@`
- `\tqt{whatever}` -> `@q{whatever}q@`

Problem arises when patterns are nested, e.g.:

`\tqt{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come \textbf{"guds morder"}: uccisore di Dei}, furono le ultime parole che sentì.`

a naive implementation:

```
import re
line = 'tqt{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come \textbf{"guds morder"}: uccisore di Dei}, furono le ultime parole che sentì.'
line = re.sub(r'\\textbf{([^}]+)}', r'@b{\1}b@', line)
line = re.sub(r'\\tqt{([^}]+)}', r'@q{\1}q@', line)
```

yields a wrong answer (`@q{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come @b{"guds morder"}q@b@: uccisore di Dei}, furono le ultime parole che sentì.`) because the intermediate form (``` \\tgt{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come @b{``guds morder''}b@: uccisore di Dei}, furono le ultime parole che sentì. ```) is somewhat ambiguous and the following pattern matches the "wrong" closing brace (the "right" string should be: `@q{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come @b{"guds morder"}b@: uccisore di Dei}q@, furono le ultime parole che sentì.`).

I thought of doing this in two steps, with some intermediate (unambiguous) form but that is overcomplex and would not help in case order of patterns is reversed (the file is long and several nesting conditions are present).

Note: nesting is always complete; i.e.; patterns never cross each other boundaries, otherwise problem would not have solution.

What is the pythonic way to do such replacements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pyparsing](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) should be good for the job. You can use `Forward` to make recursive definitions for your 'whatever'.

Here's an example, with some debugging prints to understand what's going on:

```py
import pyparsing as pp
pp.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars('') #want to preserve whitespace as is

#a placeholder, to be filled in later
whatever = pp.Forward()

textit = "\\textit{" + whatever + "}"
def textit_action(inputs):
    print('textit')
    outputs = ["@e{"+''.join(inputs[1:-1])+"}e@"]
    return outputs
textit.setParseAction(textit_action)

textbf = "\\textbf{" + whatever + "}"
def textbf_action(inputs):
    print('textbf')
    outputs = ["@b{"+''.join(inputs[1:-1])+"}b@"]
    return outputs
textbf.setParseAction(textbf_action)

tqt = "\\tqt{" + whatever + "}"
def tqt_action(inputs):
    print('tqt')
    print(inputs)
    outputs = ["@q{"+''.join(inputs[1:-1])+"}q@"]
    return outputs
tqt.setParseAction(tqt_action)

anything = pp.Regex('[^\}\{]') 
#(there is probably a more pyparsing-y way to do this)
#Matching only a single character to make this not greedy.
#Else it matches e.g. 'test \textbf', swallowing the textbf.
#This is prevented now, as or_ takes the first that matches.
def anything_action(inputs):
    print('anything')
    print(inputs)
    return inputs
anything.setParseAction(anything_action)

other_brackets = '{' + whatever + '}'
def other_brackets_action(inputs):
    print('other brackets')
    print(inputs)
    return inputs
other_brackets.setParseAction(other_brackets_action)

or_ = pp.MatchFirst([textit, textbf, tqt, other_brackets, anything] )
whatever << pp.ZeroOrMore(or_)

def whatever_action(inputs):
    print('final')
    print(inputs)
    outputs = [''.join(inputs)]
    print(outputs)
    return outputs
whatever.setParseAction(whatever_action)

whatever.parseString(r'\tqt{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come \textbf{"guds morder"}: uccisore di Dei}, furono le ultime parole che sentì.')
```

```
(['@q{Da oggi sarai conosciuto anche come @b{"guds morder"}b@: uccisore di Dei}q@, furono le ultime parole che sentì.'], {})
```

Comment: I had a look to PyParsing, but a simple example using it to solve the (very restricted) example given would be welcome.

Comment: I added a small example. Note that it will will fail on escaped brackets and probably on other untested cases as well, but it seems to do the job on the given example string.